# Message sent through Marketing Cloud isn't delivered and doesn't show up on the deliveries endpoint, what can it be?

Tags: marketing-cloud, json, rest, sms

I'm making a call to Marketing Cloud's endpoint to send SMS messages like this:

```
-- request to /sms/v1/messageContact/{messageId}/send
{
    "mobileNumbers": [
        "55009999999999"
    ],
    "subscribe": false,
    "resubscribe": false,
    "override": true,
    "messageText": "Welcome to the jungle!",
    "SendTime": "2018-05-06 00:00"
}
```

And the service's answer is the `tokenId` which can be used to verify the request status later if necessary. The problem is that the SMS is never delivered (I double-checked the number several times). Note: the message is marked as **Active**.

The request to the `deliveries` endpoint is returning me an empty array as well:

```
-- request to /sms/v1/queueMO/deliveries/{tokenId}
{
    "tracking": []
}
```

What can be preventing me from receiving the SMS?

Comment: Are you able to send that number via normal means in MobileConnect? Is the country code included? Is that phone number subscribed to a keyword already? Have you tried doing the API call without specifying send time?

Comment: The answer to all of those questions is yes. For the first one, however, the platform says it sent the message, but I do not receive it.

Comment: Does your shortcode/longcode work in the country this number is registered in? If even regular send doesn't arrive, then issue isn't with your API call. If you can, try sending regular SMS with Marketing Cloud to some coworkers number via regular way. Once it gets delivered, try sending one via API.

Answer (score 0):

Please check following things -

1. Does that particular mobile number is valid?
2. Does mobile number fall into the DND (do not disturb) category? If yes, then your sms won't be delivered to mobile number. (assuming that you're doing promotional sms)
3. Did you applied correct country code and was that phone number subscribed in mobile connect? If not then sms won't be delivered. Sometimes you have to import or subscribe all mobile numbers to a particular keyword before sending an sms (in case that mobile number wasn't subscribed earlier).

Comment: Yes. No. Yes. Turned out to be an issue on Marketing Cloud's end. After deleting everything, and recreating it again after one week, it started working.

Comment: well that's weird. I would suggest raise a support ticket with sfmc team to find out root cause.

Comment: We did. They couldn't figure it out either. This question has no answer because of that. It just started working after we redid everything...